# What is good way to write error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, syntax-error, laravel-blade

I have this error for my Error listing:

> ErrorException syntax error, unexpected '$error' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting ',' or ')' (View:
>   /var/www/html/project/resources/views/projects/create.blade.php)

My code is:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```

I don't see anything wrong help!

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I know! I don't understand why that don't accept {{ $error }} but accept {{$error}}

Comment: I suspect you had a weird special character in there, like a zero-width space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first check if any error exist than display errors.

```
  @if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
   <ul>
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
     @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
  @endif
```

Comment: Oh it was exactly my code I just put the part of interest

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the spaces like that `{{$error}}` and it works.